# Undefined property: CI_Loader::$impostazioni_model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on a calendar planning provided by `[easyappointments][1]` but now I'm stuck on this error by yesterday. In the main page `users.php` I've added the following:

```
<?php 
   require_once("application/models/impostazioni_model.php"); 

   $this->load->model('impostazioni_model');
   $this->impostazioni_model->load_colours();
?>
```

the `require_once` find correctly the file `impostazioni_model.php` but when I enter in the page `users.php` 
I see this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function load_colours() on a non-object

on this line: `$this->impostazioni_model->load_colours();`

in the class `impostazioni_model.php` I've this content:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('Direct execution not allowed.'); 

class Impostazioni_Model extends CI_Model 
{
  public function __construct() 
  {
      parent::__construct();
  }


  public function load_colours()
  {
       echo "print";
  }

}

?>
```

I've followed the `codeigniter` documentation, in particular the class model must be in capital letter so I don't know what I'm wrong. Someone could help me out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php

Comment: Which version of CI you use???

Comment: I'm using 3.0.0 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Controller**

Path - `application/controllers`

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('impostazioni_model'); //this will show "Print" word on browser. 
    }

    function index() {

    $this->impostazioni_model->load_colours();

    }

}
```

**In Model**

Path - `application/model`

```
<?php

    if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
        exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Impostazioni_model extends CI_Model {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function load_colours() {
            echo "print";
        }
    }
```

Comment: One question: you said "application/controller" I've in my folder "application/controllers", which file I must edit? The same thing on "application/model" I've "application/model" I don't know which file must b edit.

Comment: Okay but in the controllers folder I doesn't have the file "admin.php" in which file is located the class "Admin"?
The model "impostazioni" must be called in the file users.php, this file doesn't have any class and can't have a class 'cause is a mix of html, php and ajax request. This is my "user.php" file:

http://pastebin.com/JA9QHmZd

and is located in: root/application/controllers

Comment: No men. Change your controler name as ur need. I just post example

Comment: Okay now I've integrated the class inside the php file but how I can load the function of that class in the php file?

Comment: In controller check index function. Im calling method from model